# CoreImage - why the execution times are inconsistent?

Tags: ios, iphone, image, core-graphics, core-image

Here's the code which does no-op image processing with 4 frameworks - `UIKit`, `CoreGraphics`, `Image I/O` and `CoreImage`:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    var image: CGImage!
    measure("IMG IO") {
        image = self.imageIONoOp().cgImage!
        print("io: \(image.width)x\(image.height)")
    }
    measure("==== save IO") { self.save(image: image) }
}

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    var image: CGImage!
    measure("UI") {
        image = self.uiNoOp().cgImage!
        print("ui: \(image.width)x\(image.height)")
    }
    measure("==== save UI") { self.save(image: image) }
}

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    var image: CGImage!
    measure("CG") {
        image = self.cgNoOp().cgImage!
        print("cg: \(image.width)x\(image.height)")
    }
    measure("==== save CG") { self.save(image: image) }
}

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    var image: CGImage!
    measure("CIFilter") {
        let f = NoOpCIFilter()
        f.inputImage = CIImage(contentsOf: imgUrl)
        image = context.createCGImage(f.outputImage!, from: f.outputImage!.extent)!
        print("ci: \(image.width)x\(image.height)")
    }
    measure("==== save CI") { self.save(image: image) }
}
```

`self.save(image: image)` writes supplied `CGImage` to disk using `Image I/O`

---

The device is iPhone 6 plus.

When running this on 3000x2000 image, I get these:

```
io: 3000x2000
Measuring IMG IO: 115.519 milliseconds
saved 1.17mb
Measuring ==== save IO: 125.971 milliseconds

ui: 3000x2000
Measuring UI: 81.506 milliseconds
saved 1.17mb
Measuring ==== save UI: 110.822 milliseconds

cg: 3000x2000
Measuring CG: 66.13 milliseconds
saved 1.17mb
Measuring ==== save CG: 114.275 milliseconds

ci: 3000x2000
Measuring CIFilter: 100.614 milliseconds
saved 1.16mb
Measuring ==== save CI: 105.824 milliseconds
```

When, on the other hand running the code on 10800x5400 image, I get these:

```
io: 10800x5400
Measuring IMG IO: 1096.692 milliseconds
saved 21.11mb
Measuring ==== save IO: 1436.763 milliseconds

ui: 10800x5400
Measuring UI: 989.841 milliseconds
saved 21.11mb
Measuring ==== save UI: 1388.421 milliseconds

cg: 10800x5400
Measuring CG: 808.23 milliseconds
saved 21.11mb
Measuring ==== save CG: 1606.096 milliseconds

ci: 10800x5400
Measuring CIFilter: 29.509 milliseconds
saved 21.04mb
Measuring ==== save CI: 3160.284 milliseconds
```

---

Questions:

- Why for the larger image `CIFilter` operation takes less time then for the smaller image?
- Why save operation after `CIFilter` on the larger image takes twice the expected time?

Comment: A possible explanation is that Core Image processes large images only when they are consumed. Try other forms of consumption, e. g. display as large or small picture. Core Image will probably optimize the rendering process accordingly when displaying a small image.

Comment: A few thoughts. (1) How is `NoOpCIFilter` a *valid* measurement of a `CIFilter`? That makes no sense to me. It's only a valid measurement of two things - `CIContext` and `CIContext.createCGImage`, both of which are IMO poorly coded. (2) CIFilters process large images by "slicing" the image recipe into smaller "chunks", so it may well be that faster processing times will occur.

Comment: @clemens I've setup saving image to file as consumption, and it's the same in both cases. Though with larger image it looks kinda strange. Thanks

Comment: @dfd i'm just trying to get a hold on the performance of gpu processing and this is something to get me started. Next I plan to overlay some images which could be done on both cpu and gpu as a benchmark. What interests me is why in second (larger) image CoreImage has those strange timings. First (smaller) image looks more or less reasonable to me. Thanks

Comment: From *Core Image for Swift*, page 189: "Core Image splits large images into several tiles for rendering....". My take is that it may be using threading for this too. So If your large image is broken into ties that are smaller than your small image - and each tile is processed in a separate thread synchronously, it may be processed faster in the end. Just a guess.

Comment: @dfd Thanks. Is that book by Simon J Gladman? Interesting that saving takes longer for larger image comparing to the other methods. I'm assuming CGImage is always available, it's not like UIImage or CIImage may contain a recipe and be actually prepared when requested. Also, what's funny - creating of CGImage for larger image takes less time then for smaller image, and that grabs my attention.

Comment: Yes. It's written in Swift 2 and a free download nowadays, at least in the US. I've always assumed the following: (1) `UIImage` is `UIKit` and will always use the CPU. `CGImage` is `Core Graphics` and will always use the GPU. `CIImage` is `Core Image` and (by default) uses the GPU but can be configured to use the CPU (and may automatically do that sometimes. (2) **Never** use Core Image timings on the simulator. Just one time doing a straight comparison will show you what I mean. :-)

Comment: (3) Regards to processing, you are right - since Core Image is a recipe, until you call `outputImage` no processing is done.